# Amplifiying unsymmetrical voice recordings

Tags: normalize

I have several voice recordings sporting an unsymmetrical waveform (some parts already having the highest amplitude are heavily unsymmetrical).

The audio isn't very loud but can't be further amplified / normalized digitally as the samples in the unsymmetrical parts already touch the 16 bit range limit, despite no single part of the waveform actually use the 16 bit range by itself.

The unsymmetric parts are balanced in the mean, eg. they do not feature relevant DC offsets.

Is there any way using standard software tools to "rebalance" the waveform on those parts to get more headroom for amplification?

Comment: It might have to do with DC offset

Comment: Most waveforms from natural sources (voices, instruments, etc.) are asymmetrical. But it sounds like you are talking about CLIPPING not ASYMMETRY. Those are two very different things. If you are saying that you are starting with audio that is already clipped, changing its level by amplification or attenuation won't fix the clipping problem. There are some software applications that can attempt to repair clipped audio waveforms with varying success. Please provide an image showing the waveform you are asking about so that we can confirm that we are all talking about the same thing and agree on

Comment: The waveform is NOT clipped right now, but any say 10ms part of does not use the full value range. If all peaks where symmetrical, I could boost this waveform by > 3db, however as it is asymetrical, I could not boost by any amount without introducing clipping.

Comment: No, there is no mean DC offset, the 'positive' parts of the signal have much larger peak values but are rare, the 'negative' parts are more frequent and have lower peak values. So the mean is almost 0.

Comment: It almost looks like http://f-video.s3.amazonaws.com/dc-offset-removed-large.png from http://www.producenewmedia.com/asymmetric-waveforms-should-you-be-concerned/ . Only with the peaks just touching the limit.

Comment: If the peaks are already at Full Scale, then you need to use compression to boost the apparent loudness.

Comment: Well the peaks are at full scale, but not at full range, as of the asymmetry. One coul imagine that applying a DC offset would center the signal in a way that a larger range is possible without clipping.

Comment: I don't know what is the difference between "full scale" vs. "full range"? But in any case, DC offset is NOT desirable in any case. It should be removed, not deliberately introduced.  Compression is the method of dealing with the situation you describe (at least as we understand it from your verbal description.)

Comment: Why are people mentioning DC offset and clipping? This is an asymmetry problem.

Comment: We don't KNOW that it is an asymmetry problem. The OP has never provided a sample. We have only their perception of unknown validity.

Comment: Oh, I thought the [link](http://f-video.s3.amazonaws.com/dc-offset-removed-large.png) was the actual file. My bad. He says it's the same though, really. He does seem pretty adamant too that it ain't DC Offset, also, DC offset is rare these days and easily diagnosable. What he describes is an assymmetrical waveform IMO... P.S. Don't forget you can add @(user) so they are notified of your reply.

Comment: In any case, even if we don't "know" OP's problem is asymmetry, the actual question is very specifically about asymmetry.

Furthermore, applying gain compensation to an asymmetrical signal will lead to clipping earlier than a corrected signal, so I think this is bordering on "too chatty".

Answer (score 3):

I too agree that the question does not provide the right detail BUT talking about asymmetrical waveforms, the answer lies in phase rotation, the way kahn (or whatever spelling that name has) the radiowaves pioneer managed to squeeze +6 db headroom from male voices, cause this is very often in male vocal recordings (And class A amplifiers when they are driven hard)!

Another way of fighting this issue to gain some more headroom, is passing your signal through a hardware device with audio transformers!

First thing i would look for is the phase rotation plugin: play with the poles and bandwidth and in the meantime record your signal internally so you can see the results!

keep in mind, phase rotation can be found also as group delay(in audio applications), the term "phase rotator" is oftenly misused in plugin applications and what you get is plugins that just flip the phase or just ... phasers...

Here are some very usefull articles covering wave asymmetry and phase rotation as a counteraction:

http://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/q-why-do-waveforms-sometimes-look-lop-sided

http://www.producenewmedia.com/asymmetric-waveforms-should-you-be-concerned/

Scientific:
http://www.w3am.com/8poleapf.html

At last , you can also look for third party software that does the job, i bet you'll find some in form of plugin or not! :D

Good luck!

Comment: Nice answer, but unless you have to push the gain, I'd leave it alone. I have come across this before, and I needed the gain, so I just compressed it so it was more symmetrical. I can see how a phase rotator would work though.

Comment: Well compression sadly is not a solution. It might give more gain because of compression and make up gain , but it is just a counter action. My opinion is tha you should first bring the waveform to a healthy state and then compress :)

Comment: Well it seemed to work at the time anyway! So do you think phase rotation could be used to combat things like phase cancellation when summing stereo to mono?

Comment: Hmm i think what you describe is a different problem. Phase cancellation in mono "summing" should occur only if phase corellation between L & R is not correct ! Other than that when you have a healthy phase relationship you should hear the same thing only in mono. In stereo phase correlation *sometimes* is not that important and actually many times is desired as it results to stereo expansion effects. If you have a problem like that try posting a question with a sample , im sure it will be solved in no time :)

Comment: Also if you want to learn more about phase rotation i can provide the practical / creative details for you ! Its a very nice effect with various  ways of use!

Comment: I don't have any problem specifically, I am just curious as I've heard of it, but I don't think I have ever utalized it as a tool. I'm interested to see if I could use it to solve certain problems. I have iZotope's RX2 and I think I read somewhere that there are PR tools in RX2. Is that right? and yes, I'd like the details if you have them.

Comment: Well , no , phase rotation *practically* will help you create insane bass and crazy frequency sweeps. What phase rotation does is that as it rotates the actual phase it brings the high frequencies first and the bass after , so imagine a trance kick which goes "kew kew kew" , if you exaggerate the use of phase rotation you can produce this result out of simply any kick ! Its very interesting in transients and continuous sounds as well , theres a nice plugin called "disperser" it has free trial and it can be used without the fuss of poles and bands , it's fixed but still creative & useful!

Comment: Ok. I thought, or assumed it rotated the phases of the harmonics of a soundwave, is this correct?

Comment: Keep in mind that harmonics are frequencies , so you are not that far away from the concept. But when we talk about phase rotation we talk about frequencies. Harmonics are kind of a naming convention in the bottom , all are frequencies!!

Comment: Ok thanks, like I said I think I get the concept anyway. We shouldn't talk more on here. I'm going to look into this further though, I think we skipped over this concept being used as a 'tool' in university. I'm going to do some research and tests anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The unsymmetrical voice recordings you describe are perfectly 'healthy' and true to nature.

As already noted, a phase rotation tool should be able to move the high frequency, thin pulse-like peak back into the rest of the waveform.

Another method of doing this, is to use a frequency shifter, shifting by as little as a couple of Hz up or down. This is less effective, and doesn't sound great (transients are smeared)... but I've found phase rotation plugins difficult to find.